Youtube reporting API schema information
I am looking for schema information associated with Youtube's analytics reports, specifically the V1 reports defined here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports
Before I start analyzing these reports, was curious if there is any reference material that would help me get started. Youtube APIs don't have any information about the contents of each of these reports.
I looked at existing reporting API docs, and there wasn't any documentation available.

I'm not sure what you'd be looking for besides the documentation... it's literally on the page you linked to...  https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs.reports

To clarify, I am looking for information about the reports downloaded using the API. I am able to download CSVs with the API details, but before I spend time setting up my own schema in our database, I am checking to see if there is any official youtube documentation about the reports.
